# in iOS app development, i need to display some Japanese character, it's 2 bytes, but i can't find the correct encoding to use

Tags: ios, unicode, encoding, nsstring

i'm developing an iOS app and i encountered encoding problem with Japanese.

The Japanese character stream is sent to the app from a remote server, and every character has two bytes,  (including hiragana, katakana, and kanji).

Here's the code:

```
uint8_t bytes[2];

bytes[0] = firstByte;    // First byte of the Japanese character    
bytes[1] = secondByte;   // second byte,   

NSMutableData* data =   [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data appendBytes:bytes length:2];

UInt32 encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(someJapaneseEncoding);  // need to find a correct encoding to use 
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];
```

Then the code will print the *str to the screen and draw in on the phone, but the problem is that, no matter what encoding i use, the str can't be display correctly. they becomes gibberish, or space, or some other language like Korean or Thai characters, but they never be displayed in Japanese.

The encoding i have tried are (and more, i tried lots of encodings):

- NSASCIIStringEncoding　7ビットASCIIエンコード
- NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding　NeXTSTEP拡張8ビットASCIIエンコード
- NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding　日本語EUC
- NSUTF8StringEncoding　8ビットUnicode(UTF8)エンコード
- NSISOLatin1StringEncoding　ISOラテン1エンコード
- NSISOLatin2StringEncoding　ISOラテン2エンコード
- NSSymbolStringEncoding　シンボルエンコード
- NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding　損失無し7ビットASCIIエンコード
- NSShiftJISStringEncoding　シフトJIS
- NSUnicodeStringEncoding　Unicodeエンコード
- NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding　アドビスタンダードCyrillic
- NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding　Winラテン1
- NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding　Greek
- NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding　Turkish
- NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding　Winラテン1
- NSISO2022JPStringEncoding　ISO2022日本語エンコード（電子メールなど）
- NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding　MacRoman
- NSProprietaryStringEncoding

I really need help on this, i've searched online for days but no luck...please help...

Comment: You need to find out the name of the encoding on the other end. There are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: that's also another problem....i don't know what encoding they use in the server end...only know that it has 2 characters..  it's probably a linux machine...any possibilities? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Those are all NSStringEncodings, so your code isn't correct. You want, for example:

```
uint8_t bytes[2];

bytes[0] = firstByte;    // First byte of the Japanese character    
bytes[1] = secondByte;   // second byte,   

NSMutableData* data =   [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data appendBytes:bytes length:2];

NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                           encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

i.e. without the call to CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding, because you're not starting with a CFStringEncoding.

In practice, if the iPhone supports your mystery encoding I'd expect it to be NSUTF16StringEncoding, or explicitly NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding or NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding, since they're the only two-byte types.

Because you're loading the two bytes of a 16bit quantity into memory in a fixed order, your code isn't actually endian neutral. So watch for that.

Comment: It may also be ShiftJIS ( `NSShiftJISStringEncoding` )

Comment: hi, thanks a lot to your answer,@Tommy, i'm trying it although no luck yet, but i think it's getting closer. About the endian issue, will it help if i swap the two bytes? or should i swap the position of each bit? i have no idea which endian it actually is.

Comment: @chingju You would swap the bytes.